# Isolation and self-study

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

**A little background:** I am currently a sophomore (studying mathematics) at an unknown university in the Middle East. My mother is European so it does not make sense to study mathematics in the Middle East when I have the opportunity to study in Europe but the problem is that my father does not let me to live in Europe and if I will, he promised that he will cut me off without a penny (my mother does not have a job). Nevertheless I am determined to go and live with my grandparents next year but this is where the problems actually start: I missed the deadline for next year's applications and the school I want to apply does not recognize my previous studies so I have to start from the beginning. Further, my grandparents live in a small village in that European country so I won't be able to attend lectures in a school or discuss mathematics with other people (on a blackboard).

**Questions:** Now that I will be completely isolated next year, what should I do? I am interested in topology, currently taking a differential topology course (covers the first 30 pages of Milnor's Differential Point of View, have taken an algebraic topology course (homology and an introduction to fiber bundles). I am also interested in physics, mainly general relativity. Naber's Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields seems to be a good choice for self-study. Or should I strengthen my background in more foundational stuff like linear algebra, algebra, analysis for the year after? Or maybe I should do both? Also, how will I get motivated? Even now, although I am taking a course I like, I get easily distracted and don't feel like studying. If possible, how can I turn this lonely year to my advantage?

Apologies for my English and overusing the word "European". Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You study differential geometry and algebraic topology as a sophomore? Don't come in Europe, your university looks good enough :-)

Comment: You have looooooots of sites with vídeo courses ( en in youtube, and the MIT courses and etc.), and there literally thousands of mathematics books in the web that you can download and/or, at least, read on line. That's a start.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am not taking these courses officially (they are taught in different schools), I just attend the lectures for fun

Comment: By the way, Seldon, you seem to have a *very good* handle on the English language!